# Remove the profile.php?name=Username from url and replace with profile/Username

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with my php file. I want to make a site and have the url look like this

domain.com/players/username

i have my folders set up like this:
domain.com/players/players.php?username=johndoe

inside the main folder (domain.com/players/index.php) i have a search form that posts to the players.php file so that I want to make it able to search for a player by his username

So -> Remove the /players.php?username=johndoe and change it to /players/johndoe
that a user can view their profile at domain.com/players/johndoe

Thank you everyone for the help and sorry if this is a bad question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Turn on the engine:
RewriteEngine on

# Set the base to this directory:
RewriteBase /username/

# Redirect certain paths to player.php:
RewriteRule ^(username)/?$ players.php?username=$1

</IfModule>
```

This is a htaccess file, so you also have to make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server's httpd.conf file.

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: You're closing a directive that you didn't open in your code: `</IfModule>`.

Comment: Snap, your right, it was included in the file I copied it from.  I'm not sure at what point that it was deleted...  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but sadly it's not working. I want to have a /player site that has a form and then /player/username that has the profile

i have been trying almost everything has been ending up in errors

Comment: as i said your httpd.conf file may be blocking mod_rewrite permissions.  and to Gustavo, I had opened it, but whenever i used ctrl+k to make my text code i did not have the top directive selected.  Again, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: is your website on a live or local server?

Comment: It's on a live server right now

Comment: Do you have full access to the httpd.conf file?

Comment: My webspace is on my root server but I'm not sure where that file is

Comment: okay Well I hate to have you do something you are not comfortable with, but i can send you some excerpts from my book that explains it pretty well if you like

Comment: Could I please add you on skype?

Comment: hey, hows the site going bro?